# PrintableAreaHeight & PrintableAreaWidth

Tags: c#, wpf, printdialog

How to adjust `System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog.PrintableAreaHeight` & `System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog.PrintableAreaWidth` since they are read only?

Answer (score 2):

`PrintableAreaHeight` and `PrintableAreaWidth` is calculated based on the `PrintDialog.PrintTicket` that is used.  In other words they can't be adjusted because the printer that is printing the document specifies what values to use.  If you really want to change the print area, which can cause the printer to print ink on it rollers if the size is larger than what can actually be printed, you could do:

```
var pd = new PrintDialog();
if(pd.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    pd.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(newWidth, newHeight);
    pd.PrintDocument(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In WPF you can use the [PrintTicket Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printticket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog`.
This class has a lot of properties to change the aspect of the page.

In Windows Forms you can use `YourPrintDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize`.
Here is a link to MSDN: [PrinterSettings.PaperSizes Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.papersizes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I can't get this to work as the printdialog you refered to me is part of System.Windows.Forms

I am actually working with WPF